# When a font tag specifying a face that the rendered doesn't know what other font does the renderer is expected to use?

Tags: html, css, email, fonts, html-email

I'm working on an email signature and was wondering how I could define a set of fonts to choose from.

I've seen that in HTML. We can define a list of font names and the renderer chooses the first that it finds on the target system.

However, in emails, I usually see the `<font>` tag being used. But from what I know that doesn't seem to allow for a choice between more than one font face. I'm wondering whether there is a way to let the renderer decide which font to choose based on what's available on the viewer's platform and still have an email signature that works.

From what I can see, the following doesn't work:

```
<font name="Tahoma">
  <font name="Avenir">
    Alexis Wilke
  </font>
</font>
```

If my computer doesn't have `Avenir` installed, it falls back to the renderer default, not `Tahoma`.

Should I have a `<span>` tag with a `style="font-family: ..."` attribute as well? If the renderer doesn't understand the style attribute, it could fallback on the `<font>` tag? Would that be the best practice?

```
<font face="Tahoma">  <!-- would this one ever be useful? -->
  <font face="Avenir">
    <span style="font-family: Avenir, Tahoma, sans-serif;">
      Alexis Wilke
    </span>
  </font>
</font>
```

I'm testing with Thunderbird and that works, but I'm wondering whether this is sufficiently universal.

Comment: "... `<font>`... from what I know that doesn't seem to allow for a choice between more than one font face". According to the HTML5 & HTML 4.01 specs, it should do so. But I can't say how well it would work in email clients.

Comment: Oh! I see, with multiple names inside the attribute like so `<font color="red" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" size="+1">`. I can at least use that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<font face="Tahoma">  <!-- would this one ever be useful? -->
  <font face="Avenir">
    <span style="font-family: Avenir, Tahoma, sans-serif;">
      Alexis Wilke
    </span>
  </font>
</font>
```

To answer your question on the first line, `<font face="Tahoma">` would never be used in this case, nor would `<font face="Avenir">`.

As you and Alohci discussed in the comments, you can place multiple font names in a `style` attribute. Each system will try the first one, if it doesn't have the font installed, it'll move on the next one, and so on down the chain until it finds a match. Specifying `sans-serif` at the end tells a system to use whatever it's default sans-serif font is, so the chain will likely end here if it hasn't already.

---

If you're working on an HTML email signature I'd suggest using a `<span style="">` approach rather than `<font face="">`. Probably get better coverage across email clients.

So you can remove the `<font>` tags from your example and go with something like this:

```
<span style="font-family: Avenir, Tahoma, sans-serif;"> <!-- or a <div> -->
  Alexis Wilke
</span>
```

Comment: So are you saying that all modern email systems are good enough to understand a `<span>` rendering the `<font>` tag useless? (which would be great!)

Comment: Yes! I work on email regularly and it's been years since I've used the `<font>` tag. Generally HTML2 tags are supported and https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ is a good reference for CSS.